# How to check if value is a map or a string in apache velocity

Tags: velocity

I use apache velocity to render templates. Now, the problem is that I have an API data feed with values that can either contain a map or a string. I iterate through the list and put values in a table. This is a sample of the feed am getting:

```
{
    "Secondary Camera": 
    {
        "Key1": 
        {
           "present": "true",
           "value": "2 Megapixel"
        },
        "Key2": 
        {
           "present": "true","value": "0.3 Megapixel"
        }
    }
},
{
    "Other Camera Features": 
    {
        "Key1": "Auto Focus, Panorama, Photo Sphere, Lens Blur",
        "Key2": "Panorama Shot"
    }
},
```

With this the Key1/Key2 values are sometimes string and sometimes they are a map. Is there a fool proof way to make this work with [strict mode](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#strictreferences) on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. the main idea is to directly inspect values classes.

The following code

```
#set(
  $map = {
    'key1' : 'string_value',
    'key2' : [ 'array', 'value' ],
    'key3' : { 'map' : 'value'  }
  }
)

#set ( $obj = '' ) ## dummy object
#set ( $string_class = $obj.class.forName('java.lang.String') )
#set ( $map_class = $obj.class.forName('java.util.Map') )

#foreach( $value in $map )
  value class name = $value.class.name
  #if ( $string_class.isAssignableFrom($value.class) )
    value is a string
  #elseif ( $map_class.isAssignableFrom($value.class) )
    value is a map
  #end
#end
```

will produce:

```
value class name = java.lang.String
  value is a string
value class name = java.util.LinkedHashMap
  value is a map
```

You can also test directly if an object is a class with `$obj.class.name == 'java.lang.String'`, but you cannot do it for maps this way, since `java.util.Map` is only a root abstract interface for all map classes.

Warning: some Velocity configurations (known as *secure*) will forbid the access to the `class` property of objects.

Comment: Will definitely try and this and post results. For now, this looks solid. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

While trying to get a generic VTL template for APIGateway, I came to this condition that works in this particular environment. Apparently when toString() is applied to a Map this string is printed "[object Object]", so we can use this trick to distinguish between a Map and other types. This doesn't require access to "class". It doesn't feel particularly robust to rely on this hack, but so far is the best I got. So I'm sharing here for the record.

```
#if ($cdrField.toString() != "[object Object]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @claude-brisson's answer, but was unable to make that work with AWS AppSync. My approach is less sophisticated, and I hate that it checks an object's class by its string name, but it gets the job done.

```
#foreach( $entry in $ctx.args.entrySet() )
    #if( $entry.value.class.name == "java.util.LinkedHashMap" )
       ##Do something if value is a map
    #elseif( $entry.value.class.name == "java.lang.String" )
       ##Do something if value is a string
    #elseif( $entry.value.class.name == "java.util.ArrayList" )
       ##Do something if value is a list
    #end
#end
```

Where `$ctx.args` is a map of input arguments.